# Momentjs changes the timezone value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have these lines of code

`const startTime = '2017-09-12T09:00:00-04:00';
 let s = moment(startTime);
 s.format()`

These lines output `'2017-09-12T13:00:00+00:00'`

How can I still get the output as my previous string? `'2017-09-12T09:00:00-04:00'`

I've tried going through the documentation and tried using   `utcOffset()` `s.utc().format()`   after looking at some other answers on stackoverflow

I also perform add operation on time but that doesn't seem relevant at the "moment".

Comment: Your pun drove me away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var startTime = '2017-09-12T09:00:00-04:00';
var s = moment.parseZone(startTime);
s = s.add(1, 'd');
console.log(s.format()); //2017-09-13T09:00:00-04:00

startTime = '2017-09-12T09:00:00+00:00';
s = moment.parseZone(startTime);
console.log(s.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> Moment's string parsing functions like moment(string) and moment.utc(string) accept offset information if provided, but convert the resulting Moment object to local or UTC time.
>
> In contrast, moment.parseZone() parses the string but keeps the resulting Moment object in a fixed-offset timezone with the provided offset in the string.
>
> -- [Moment.js Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/)

Comment: this is the most closest answer I've gotten. Thanks! but there's a problem now I get `2017-09-12T09:00:00Z` when I pass `2017-09-12T09:00:00+00:00`

Comment: Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. +00:00 is equal to 'Z'.

Comment: is some option in moment that would allow me to keep it as +00:00?

Comment: @RobG As I've already mentioned that I've read the documentation. I could have always used the format string but given the number of options that are available with moment I won't be surprised if an option like that existed and I just oversaw it.

Comment: @MahinKhan—I tried "+-HH:mm" with the latest version of Moment and it doesn't seem to work, it puts the time in the offset. But "z" works (updated answer to include runnable snippet). It doesn't seem to matter if the original string is "Z" or "+00:00". ;-)

Comment: That seems to cover all the cases! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the timezones in moments js.

Try using this and see if it shows the desired results:

```
s.tz('America/New_York').format()
```

All you have to do is to provide correct timezone in the tz method and voila.

Reference: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 7am EST

jun.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST
dec.tz('Asia/Tokyo').format('ha z');           // 9pm JST

jun.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 10pm EST
dec.tz('Australia/Sydney').format('ha z');     // 11pm EST
```

Comment: my code doesn't have information about the timezone. All I get is the string `2017-09-12T09:00:00-04:00`

Comment: That -04:00 is the timezone.

Comment: @DanielBeck yeah, I wanted a solution where I didn't have to parse the string itself.

Comment: I think we might be talking past each other a bit here? You *definitely* shouldn't parse the string.  Call the date object's `tz(yourTimezoneHere)` for whatever timezone you want to display the date in (as shown above), and output that in your desired format (which I believe is just `format()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
const startTime = '2017-09-12T09:00:00-04:00';
let s = moment(startTime);
s.utcOffset(120).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')

console.log(s.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
```

Use the utcOffset(120) to change timezone. Value is in minutes. Read more here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```